# My code was able to execute at c++ 2010 but when i return and use mine which is c++ 2008 it has errors

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct attendance
{
    string date;
};
struct info
{
    string subject_code;
    string lecturer_name;
};
struct student_info
{
    string name;
    string ic;
};
int inputData(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info   *student2, student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5);
int editData(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info *student2,    student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5);
void Attendance(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info *student2, student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5,   attendance att1[][10], attendance att2[][10], attendance att3[][10], attendance att4[][10],  attendance att5[][10]);

int main()
{
    info *subject = new info[5];
    int arrSize=5;
    student_info *student1= new student_info[arrSize];
    student_info *student2= new student_info[arrSize];
    student_info *student3= new student_info[arrSize];
    student_info *student4= new student_info[arrSize];
    student_info *student5= new student_info[arrSize];
    attendance att1 [5][10];
    attendance att2 [5][10];
    attendance att3 [5][10];
    attendance att4 [5][10];
attendance att5 [5][10];
char choice = ' ';
char choice2 = ' ';
bool reloop = true;

while(reloop)
{
    cout<<"****Default number of student = 5, default day to record = 10****"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"****Main Menu****"<<endl;
    cout<<"a. Input all subject's data"<<endl;
    cout<<"b. Edit subject's data"<<endl;
    cout<<"c. Input student's attendance"<<endl;
    cout<<"d. Exit & Save as .Txt"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nPlease enter your choice: ";
    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        system("CLS");
        inputData(subject,arrSize,student1,student2,student3,student4,student5);
        reloop = true;
        break;

    case 'b':
    case 'B':
        system("CLS");
        editData(subject,arrSize,student1,student2,student3,student4,student5);
        reloop = true;
        break;

    case 'c':
    case 'C':
        system("CLS");
        Attendance(subject,arrSize,student1,student2,student3,student4,student5,att1,att2,att3,att4,att5);
        reloop = true;
        break;

    case'd':
    case'D':
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Do you like to save all data in files before exit? Insert Y for Yes / Any key for no"<<endl;
        cin>>choice2;
        if( (choice2=='y') || choice2=='Y')
        {
            ofstream outfile(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt");

            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile <<"Student Name           : "<< student1[i].name <<endl;
                outfile <<"Student Ic             : "<< student1[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile<<att1[i][j].date;
                    outfile<<"\t";
                }
                outfile <<endl;
            }

            ofstream outfile1(subject[1].subject_code += ".txt");
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile1 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Student Name           : "<< student2[i].name <<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student2[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile1<<att2[i][j].date;
                    outfile1<<"\t";
                }

                outfile1 <<endl;
            }

            ofstream outfile2(subject[2].subject_code += ".txt");
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile2 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Student Name           : "<< student3[i].name <<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student3[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile2<<att3[i][j].date;
                    outfile2<<"\t";
                }
                outfile2 <<"\n";
            }

            ofstream outfile3(subject[3].subject_code += ".txt");
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile3 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Student Name           : "<< student4[i].name <<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student4[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile3<<att4[i][j].date;
                    outfile3<<"\t";
                }
                outfile3 <<"\n";
            }

            ofstream outfile4(subject[4].subject_code += ".txt");
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile4 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Student Name           : "<< student5[i].name <<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student5[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile4<<att5[i][j].date;
                    outfile4<<"\t";
                }
                outfile4 <<"\n";
            }

        }
        reloop = false;
        break;

    default:
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Invalid selection. Please try again.\n"<<endl;
        cin.clear();
        string ignoreLine; //read the invalid student into it
        getline(cin, ignoreLine); //read the line till next space
        continue;
        reloop = true;
        break;

    }
}

cin.get ();
cin.ignore ( 1 , '\n' );

return 0;
}
int inputData(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info     *student2, student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5)
{

int counter = 1;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter the subject code of this subject :";
    cin>>subject[i].subject_code; 
    cout<<"Enter the lecturer name of this subject :"; 
    cin>>subject[i].lecturer_name; 

    if (counter == 1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
            cin>>student1[i].name;

            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
            cin>>student1[i].ic;
        }
    }

    else if (counter==2)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
            cin>>student2[i].name;

            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
            cin>>student2[i].ic;
        }
    }

    else if (counter==3)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
            cin>>student3[i].name;

            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
            cin>>student3[i].ic;
        }
    }

    else if (counter==4)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
            cin>>student2[i].name;

            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
            cin>>student2[i].ic;
        }
    }

    else if (counter==5)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
            cin>>student5[i].name;

            cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
            cin>>student5[i].ic;
        }
    }

    counter++;
    cout<<"---------------------------------------"<<endl;
}
return arrSize,arrSize,arrSize,arrSize,arrSize;
}
int editData(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info *student2, student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5)
{
int ch;
cout<<"Subject List"<<endl;
cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Please choose the subject you wish to edit by entering the index number :";
cout<<"1. "<<subject[0].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"2. "<<subject[1].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"3. "<<subject[2].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"4. "<<subject[3].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"5. "<<subject[4].subject_code<<endl;
cin>>ch;

switch(ch)
{
case 1:
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
        cin>>student1[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
        cin>>student1[i].ic;
    }break;

case 2:
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
        cin>>student2[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
        cin>>student2[i].ic;
    }break;

case 3:
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
        cin>>student3[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
        cin>>student3[i].ic;
    }break;

case 4:
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
        cin>>student2[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
        cin>>student2[i].ic;
    }break;

case 5:
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s name: ";
        cin>>student5[i].name;

        cout<<"Enter student"<<(i+1)<<"'s ic: ";
        cin>>student5[i].ic;
    }break;
default :
    cout<<"Invalid Selection. Please try again."<<endl;
    break;
}
return arrSize,arrSize,arrSize,arrSize,arrSize;
}
void Attendance(info* subject, int arrSize, student_info *student1, student_info *student2, student_info *student3, student_info *student4, student_info *student5, attendance att1[][10], attendance att2[][10], attendance att3[][10], attendance att4[][10], attendance att5[][10])
{

int ch1;
cout<<"Subject List"<<endl;
cout<<"-----------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"1. "<<subject[0].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"2. "<<subject[1].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"3. "<<subject[2].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"4. "<<subject[3].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"5. "<<subject[4].subject_code<<endl;
cout<<"Please choose from the subject list that you wish to edit by entering the index number :"<<endl;
cin>>ch1;

switch(ch1)
{
case 1:
    cout<<"Enter the date by following this pattern Date_Month_Year, example: 6_7_2014"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter absent if the student is absent"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student name:"<<student1[i].name<<endl;
        for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Day"<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>att1[i][j].date;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }break;
case 2:
    cout<<"Enter the date by following this pattern Date_Month_Year, example: 6_7_2014"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter absent if the student is absent"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student name:"<<student2[i].name<<endl;
        for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Day"<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>att2[i][j].date;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }break;
case 3:
    cout<<"Enter the date by following this pattern Date_Month_Year, example: 6_7_2014"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter absent if the student is absent"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student name:"<<student3[i].name<<endl;
        for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Day"<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>att3[i][j].date;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }break;
case 4:
    cout<<"Enter the date by following this pattern Date_Month_Year, example: 6_7_2014"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter absent if the student is absent"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student name:"<<student4[i].name<<endl;
        for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Day"<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>att4[i][j].date;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }break;
case 5:
    cout<<"Enter the date by following this pattern Date_Month_Year, example: 6_7_2014"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter absent if the student is absent"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Student name:"<<student5[i].name<<endl;
        for (int j=0;j<7;j++)
        {
            cout<<"Day"<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>att5[i][j].date;
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }break;
default: 
    cout<<"Invalid Selection. Please  try again"<<endl;break;
}
}
```

The error still present itself in

```
        ofstream outfile(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
```

The error is

> 1>c:\users\userpc\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\assignment_2\assignment_2\assignment_2.cpp(84) : error C2664: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char *'

### Update

I changed

```
            ofstream outfile1(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt");
```

to

```
            ofstream outfile1(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
```

(and same for `subject[1]` etc.) but still get the same error.

NEW EDIT!

```
    case'd':
    case'D':
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Do you like to save all data in files before exit? Insert Y for Yes / Any key for no"<<endl;
        cin>>choice2;
        if( (choice2=='y') || choice2=='Y')
        {
            ofstream outfile(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();

            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile <<"Student Name           : "<< student1[i].name <<endl;
                outfile <<"Student Ic             : "<< student1[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile<<att1[i][j].date;
                    outfile<<"\t";
                }
                outfile <<endl;
            }

            ofstream outfile1(subject[1].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile1 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Student Name           : "<< student2[i].name <<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student2[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile1 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile1<<att2[i][j].date;
                    outfile1<<"\t";
                }

                outfile1 <<endl;
            }

            ofstream outfile2(subject[2].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile2 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Student Name           : "<< student3[i].name <<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student3[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile2 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile2<<att3[i][j].date;
                    outfile2<<"\t";
                }
                outfile2 <<"\n";
            }

            ofstream outfile3(subject[3].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile3 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Student Name           : "<< student4[i].name <<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student4[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile3 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile3<<att4[i][j].date;
                    outfile3<<"\t";
                }
                outfile3 <<"\n";
            }

            ofstream outfile4(subject[4].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();
            for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
            {
                outfile4 <<"-----List-----"<<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Student Name           : "<< student5[i].name <<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Student Ic             : "<< student5[i].ic<<endl;
                outfile4 <<"Attendance             : ";
                for (int j=0; j<7; j++)
                {
                    outfile4<<att5[i][j].date;
                    outfile4<<"\t";
                }
                outfile4 <<"\n";
            }

        }
        reloop = false;
        break;
```

error code

1>c:\users\userpc\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\assignment_2\assignment_2\assignment_2.cpp(84) : error C2664: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream(const char *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char *'

with
[_Elem=char,_Traits=std::char_traits]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Does this make any sense?

Okay this code has become

```
ofstream outfile((subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str());
```

now another error has occur.

1>c:\users\userpc\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\assignment_2\assignment_2\assignment_2.cpp(100) : error C2374: 'outfile' : redefinition; multiple initialization

I am trying to see through my code, just posting in case I get to a dead end

Comment: You don't need so many lines of code illustrate the problem, learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @YuHao Its my second time posting question I dint know there is this guide. You have my thanks

Comment: If you have a new problem not related to the first problem, you should post a new question. In this case `'outfile' : redefinition;`  means you tried to have 2 variables of the same name, `outfile`.  I'm guessing you copy-pasted your fix for the `ofstream outfile(`... line without changing the variable name

Comment: Thank you @mattmcnabb you are my savior I think I am getting c++ more and more now. Dunno what I will do without you peoples.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ please.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
subject[0].subject_code += ".txt"
```

to

```
(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str()
```

Your later version compiler obviously has an extension to take `std::string` here.

NB. Investigate using loops and/or functions instead of copy-pasting a block of code 5 times and changing a few numbers

Comment: `(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str()`

Still present the error there, is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Read your error messages carefully, probably you fixed it there but did not fix the other copy-pasted places with the same problem (`subject[1]` etc.)

Comment: NcNabb I did double checking throughout the code, and read the error message which lead me back to the first one which is `subject [0]` sorry if I cause confusion.. do you need the full code?

Comment: Yes, post the change that you made, and the new error message

Comment: ncnabb I edited since i cant post new answer . With full coding and edits from your teaching. Many thanks for helps

Comment: You stuck `.c_str();` on the end of the line. That was not my recommended change, please read my post again.

Comment: Also, don't edit your original code as it makes it confusing for anyone else seeing the question for the first time. Instead, put your updates at the end of your post in a new section.

Comment: Okay taken note on how to edit. And for the changes your recommended change without semicolons? I did that also and the same error occurs that why i put the semicolons.

Comment: No, you aren't reading my post. change **exactly** the text that I put first, to **exactly** the text that I put second. Leave anything else unchanged.

Comment: I try again just with changing only your exact text. still same error, sorry first time it was my mistake now I change only your text (and repeated for the another 4 time )

Comment: Post what you have got this time. (don't delete any txt in your post, add new stuff to the end)

Comment: Added the edited part and i think same error occurs.. Its getting to my head now this is really a fun and headache part about programming

Comment: Your "new edit" still has the broken `ofstream outfile(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();`. And don't repaste your whole code each time, just show what you changed

Comment: Now i really do not get it.. does it mean that instead of `ofstream outfile(subject[0].subject_code += ".txt").c_str();` what do i write?

Comment: Please forgive me.. i started c++ like a month ago.. while my lecturer did not teach me completely. i relied on books and guide to do this

Comment: here is an example. if you have `xxxAxxx` and the instruction is "replace A with BCDEF" then the result is `xxxBCDEFxxx` .  (Not `xxxAxxxF` as you have done)

Comment: Attention to detail is really important in programming, that is why i say it this way instead of just copy-pasting the answers

Comment: To put it another way: you could take your current code, delete the characters in my first line, then insert the characters in my second line where they were.  Don't muck with any other characters on your line.

Comment: okay i finally get what you meant.. thanks this solved a problem which resulted in another. I will edit and try to understand better this time.

Comment: OK. Don't edit the answer into your post tho, just accept my answer